# Node.JS on Bluemix - Attaching SSO fail

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I'm using the IBM Bluemix platform and I'm trying to add an SSO login page on top of a super basics Node JS app as security. I've been following this guide here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index-gentopic2.html#task_configuringapp

However, all I get is an error : **"Cannot GET /"**

This is my app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport'); 
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

//create a new express server
var app = express();

// SSO

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({resave: 'true', saveUninitialized: 'true' , secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user);
}); 

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
   done(null, obj);
});         

// VCAP_SERVICES contains all the credentials of services bound to
// this application. For details of its content, please refer to
// the document or sample of each service.  
var services = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES || "{}");
var ssoConfig = services.SingleSignOn[0]; 
var client_id = ssoConfig.credentials.clientId;
var client_secret = ssoConfig.credentials.secret;
var authorization_url = ssoConfig.credentials.authorizationEndpointUrl;
var token_url = ssoConfig.credentials.tokenEndpointUrl;
var issuer_id = ssoConfig.credentials.issuerIdentifier;
var callback_url = 'https://sso-test-6.mybluemix.net/auth/sso/callback';        

var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
                 authorizationURL : authorization_url,
                 tokenURL : token_url,
                 clientID : client_id,
                 scope: 'openid',
                 response_type: 'code',
                 clientSecret : client_secret,
                 callbackURL : callback_url,
                 skipUserProfile: true,
                 issuer: issuer_id}, 
    function(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done)  {
                process.nextTick(function() {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        done(null, profile);
            })
}); 

passport.use(Strategy); 
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {})); 

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
                req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}

app.get('/auth/sso/callback',function(req,res,next) {               
    var redirect_url = req.session.originalUrl;                
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
            successRedirect: redirect_url,                                
            failureRedirect: '/failure',                        
 })(req,res,next);
});

app.get('/failure', function(req, res) { 
    res.send('login failed'); });

//get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, function() {

    // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

I feel Like I'm doing something very stupid? But I can't figure it out -.-

Comment: It looks like you don't have a route defined for "/". What happens if you try to go to "/login"?

Comment: Could you please add here log file? You can get it with cf <app> logs --recent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a route '/' and then redirect users to login.

For example:

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
         res.send('Single Sign On <a href="/login">Login</a>\n');
    });
```

You can see a good example in the link below:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-bluemix-single-sign-on-app/index.html#N1040F

Comment: You are a star! I get the "login in" text now and consequently I see the SSO default login page.

However, when I login (correctly) I get:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined
   at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport-idaas-openidconnect/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:50:35
   at pass (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:267:43)
   at serialized (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:276:7)
   at /home/vcap/app/app.js:18:4
   at pass (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:284:9)
+ a few more lines :-(

Comment: It can't be determined without seeing more of your current code, but you may be hitting the issue documented at https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/400.  If you're using the latest 'passport' module, you may need to use the 'passport-strategy' module.  See the GitHub issue for more information.

Comment: I was able to recreate the issue. I didn't try passport-strategy, but moving to passport 0.2.2 works for me. I can try later with passport-strategy and let you know as well.